why my discord doesnt stop sending all stream notifications?
I try to make a bot by myself who can send notif twitch streams. like streamcord, etc..
The thing is I have many streamers set in my json file, if both are streaming at the same time, my bot spam their notif one after the other.
(forgive my english)
here's my code:
# Returns true if online, false if not.
def checkStream(streamer_name):
    stream = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login=' + streamer_name, headers=headers)
    stream_data = stream.json()
    
    if len(stream_data['data']) == 1:
        return True, stream_data
    else:
        return False, stream_data
    
# Execute when bot is started
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def streamNotifs():
        # Opens and reads the json file
        with open('C:/Users/trada/Desktop/ZenithBOTv0.2/DEV/scripts/streamers.json', 'r') as file:
            streamers = json.loads(file.read())
        
        channel = client.get_channel(1270192042722590750)

        for user_id, twitch_name, in streamers.items():
            
            status, stream_data = checkStream(twitch_name)

            with open('C:/Users/trada/Desktop/ZenithBOTv0.2/DEV/scripts/data.json', 'w') as file:
                file.write(json.dumps(stream_data))
            
            started_at = stream_data['data'][0]['started_at']
            user = client.get_user(int(user_id))

            if status is True:
                async for message in channel.history().flatten():

                    if str(user.mention) in message.content and started_at in message.content:
                        break

                    else:                        
                        await channel.send(
                            f'{user.mention} is now streaming on Twitch!'
                            f'\nhttps://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}'
                            f'\nstream started at: {started_at}')
                        print(f"{user} started streaming. Sending a notification.")
                        break


            
            
    streamNotifs.start()
client.run(TOKEN)

